# Can I add some PHP code into an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently running a script that pulls back transaction data (one line for each transaction) from a database with the following SQL script, which is being run in MySQL Workbench.

```
SELECT 
id,
merchant_id, 
affiliate_id, 
date, 
sale_amount, 
commission, 
ip

FROM transactions.transaction201505
```

One of the columns in the table t.transactions is IP address. Is there a way to embed this PHP script (or a function to this effect) within an SQL script:
`php function geoip_country_name_by_addr` http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php

I have seen many examples of adding MySQL to PHP but would like to essentially add in Country/ City of sale to my data the other way around, so that the result could look like the sample below, which could be run off a tool such as MySQL Workbench. I don't have access to run PHP scripts on this database, and therefore need a solution with SQL.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer on this.

Jamie

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible. You could write a UDF (user define function) in an exteranl module (e.g. a .DLL, .so or .dylib) but using PHP in such a module is probably not possible either (because PHP is a scripting language and you would need to compile your UDF into binary code). However, MySQL has a number of built-in functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html). Even though not what you want here.